# How to enable package controls in project properties

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When you create for example .Net Standard project you will see a package tab in project properties. I see it now, but to my surprise most of the controls on this tab is disabled (and empty, i.e. disabled=empty). If it matters, the project is [FSharp.Data](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data).

The odd thing is, all those fields have values really, I can edit project directly, and making package works with those "hidden" values. The only thing missing, I don't see values in UI and cannot edit them directly.

My question is how to enable all controls in package tab?